# how much fragments do I require?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I currently have 10 activities. One is the menu activities and the rest are the categories activities and I currently have created one fragment called menu fragment. How much more fragments will I need to create?

I want to create from fragments from menu pages to other pages as well. for example I want to display menu page on one side and the categories on the other side once clicked on one of the activities.

I can only find list view and detail examples. Do I need to create fragments for each activity and how much fragments need creating. Do I create a new large layout xml.file Please advise.

actvitymain.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/museumicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/theatreicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/fooddrink_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/foodicon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/leisure_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/leisureicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/shopping_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/shoppingicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leisure_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leisure_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/histroy_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/historicalicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shopping_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shopping_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/park_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/parkicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/familyfun_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/familyfunicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/park_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/park_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/travelinfor_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/travelicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/familyfun_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/familyfun_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

menufragment.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MenuFragment">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/museumicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/theatreicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/fooddrink_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/foodicon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/leisure_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/leisureicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/shopping_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/shoppingicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leisure_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leisure_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/histroy_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/historicalicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shopping_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shopping_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/park_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/parkicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/familyfun_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/familyfunicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/park_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/park_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/travelinfor_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/travelicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/familyfun_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/familyfun_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

museumactivity. XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            ></include>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/museum_icon"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/museumicon"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/theatre_icon"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/theatreicon"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/museum_icon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/museum_icon"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/fooddrink_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/foodicon"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/leisure_icon"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/leisureicon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/shopping_icon"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/shoppingicon"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leisure_icon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leisure_icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/histroy_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/historicalicon"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shopping_icon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shopping_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/park_icon"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/parkicon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/familyfun_icon"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/familyfunicon"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/park_icon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/park_icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:id="@+id/travelinfor_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/travelicon"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/familyfun_icon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/familyfun_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

theatreactivity.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Menufragment"
        android:name="com.bradvisor.bradvisor.MenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/logofinal"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/theatrehead"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/theatrehead"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: THis question is unanswerable.  You can write an Android app with 0 fragments.  Or with hundreds.  Fragments are a convenient way of reusing and grouping UI elements with a common controller. The correct time to use it is an architectural decision and depends on how you're writing the app.

Comment: I want to create fragments as I want to make my app compatible with tablet sizes. for example on one side I want to have menu page with nine image buttons once user clicks on a imagebutton it will show the selected actvity on the other page, E.G, menu page and museum page on another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Google documentation,

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. By dividing the layout of an activity into fragments, you become able to modify the activity's appearance at runtime and preserve those changes in a back stack that's managed by the activity.

How to divide and when to divide is, as the developer, up to you. If you think an activity is too heavy to handle, break it down as modular and reusable fragments. If multiple activities share same UI portions, pull it as fragment.

From the code given what I can suggest is, layouts for `actvitymain.XML`, `menufragment.XML` and `museumactivity. XML` has almost the same UI. So you can pull it as a fragment and include it in those 3 XML files.

Comment: Shall I create 10 fragments and leave the 10 activities. What do you think?

Comment: I can't give you a complete solution. It's up to you. Read my suggestion in the edited answer

Comment: Is their not an easy for. for example make the menu activity a fragment so then I will have menu fragment then you I  load menu other activities from the menu container.